# Getting multiple element values using DOM query in for..in Loop

Tags: javascript, object, for-in-loop

HI i am practicing resume creator app using JavaScript. i wanted to take all user inputs using gelements by id method in a loop.

***when i am trying getting error of null regarding value property***

without loop:

```
const fullName = document.getElementById("fullName"); // Getting Text from input
  const fullNameT = document.getElementById("fullNameT"); // Writing fullName in template
  
  fullName.innerText = fullNameT;
```

in that case i have to write multiple inputs, so i am trying in different method using for..in loop with object:

```
const ResumeGenValues = {
  fullNameT: "name",
  phoneNumberT: "phone",
  mailT: "email",
  addressT: "address",
  linkedInT: "linked-in",
  objectivesT: "objectives",
  workExperienceT: "work-experience",
  academicQualificationT: "academic-qualification",
};

for (const key in ResumeGenValues) {
    const GenEl = document.getElementById(key).value;
    document.getElementById(ResumeGenValues[key]).innerText = GenEl;
  }
```

In above i prepared an object with inputelement => templateElement to paste.

I am facing error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
```

How i can fix this error?

Comment: The error means that one of your calls to `.getElementById()` is returning `null`, meaning that there is no element on the page with that id.

Comment: Uhaaa, i got it, when i am individually checking i found it. thank you